# Issues with printing in python a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I'm new in the magic python world.

I have a problem: I save data from a file in a list of array (13 arrays of 130 element each) but when I try to print the values, only the same values with bracket are printed .

I defined the list and the array in this way:

```
List    = []
v = np.ndarray(shape=(130,1),dtype=float)
```

After I fill my data structure from the file

```
f=open(filename, 'r').readlines()
k = 0

for i in range(0,13):
    for j in range(0,130):
        v[j] = float(f[k])
        k += 1 
    List.append(v)
```

In the file I have for each line a float value and the total length is 13*130.

I don't even know if I feed correctly my data structure, what I only know is that the function that I would like to use expect a list of array instead of a matrix.

I tried different way for seeing if I saved in a correct way the data.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please edit the original question to clarify your problem.
What seems to have confused people is that you posted code for building the lists, when the problem seems to be the way you print them.  Post the printing code, the output from that, and then the output you would like.  This will get you better answers.  See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate `v` in every iteration of the outer loop:

```
for i in range(0,13):
    v = np.ndarray(shape=(130,1),dtype=float)
    for j in range(0,130):
        v[j] = float(f[k])
        k += 1 
    List.append(v)
```

Otherwise, you're just updating the same reference over and over again (`list.append` only appends the *reference* to the list, does not copy the list in question).

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `for i in List: print(i)`

If you do not want the brackets to be displayed : `for i in a: print(' '.join(map(str,i)))`

But if you want to have constant row widths, create a function that returns a string of the float of constant length :

```
def auxString(float, length):
    s = str(float)
    s+=(length-len(s))*' '
    return s
string = lambda length: lambda float: auxString(float,length)
for i in List:
    print(' '.join(map(string(5),i))) #if the maximum length of your string of float is 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But do you know how to print without bracket?

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is printing without the brackets, then I think what you want (see me comment on the post) is the following:

```
for row in list:
    for item in row:
        print item,
    print ""    # print a newline
```